# Interface inheritance in c#: property does not inherit get accessor

Tags: c#, .net

Consider the following code:

```
public interface IFoo
{
    int Bar { get; }
}

public interface IModifiableFoo : IFoo
{
    int Bar { set; }
}

public class FooImpl : IModifiableFoo
{
    public int Bar { get; set; }
}

static void Main()
{
    IModifiableFoo f = new FooImpl();
    int bar = f.Bar; // Compiler error
}
```

This is the error message:

> error CS0154: The property or indexer 'MyNamespace.IModifiableFoo.Bar' cannot be used in this context because it lacks the get accessor

Since `IModifiableFoo` inherits `IFoo`, the `get` accessor (i.e. `get_Bar()` method) should be accessible. What is going on here?

Note: This is different from question [Adding setter to inherited read-only property in C# interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36907765/adding-setter-to-inherited-read-only-property-in-c-sharp-interface) because that question does not address compiler error in calling getter via writable interface.

Comment: You should have gotten [a compiler warning](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s8070fc.aspx) when you did this, it is clue to what is going wrong. Also, the question you linked to is still the same problem, they just did not do the next step of ignoring the warning and trying to use the property anyway. EDIT: Actually, reading it more closely, it is not the same problem, because they use `get; set;t` in the derived interface but you are only using `set;`

Comment: Maybe it's because your second Bar shadows the first? What if you cast to IFoo specifically ?

Comment: Visual Studio 2012 gives me the warning "'Test.IFodifiableFoo.Bar' hides inherited member 'Test.IFoo.Bar'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended." This sure looks like the same issue as in the question you linked.

Comment: Oh. The standard "I'm programmer, I don't care about warnings" thing.

Comment: Actually, this is horrible example of interface inheritance. Why do you need this?

Comment: @Euphoric ✓Disable All Warnings ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is that your `IModifiableFoo` interface's property hides the one it gets inherited from `IFoo`, instead of overriding it. So if you want your `get` functionality in your derived interface, you have to explicitly add it.

Actually, you'd better mark your `Bar` property in `IModifiableFoo` with `new` keyword, to explicitly show that it hides something behind, in order to not get confused when looking up the code.

Comment: sure, thanks for reminding)

Answer (score 2):

Getters and setters are not individual members. So a setter in one interface does not add to the getter of the base interface. Instead, interfaces only define members, and that member here is either a readable or writable property.

The inheriting interface defines a property (a member) with the same name as the base interface. So it will hide the base interface’s member. So with two interfaces, you now have two members you could explicitly implement:

```
int IFoo.Bar { get; }
int IModifiableFoo.Bar { set; }
```

Note that the compiler should give you a warning about this behavior, and advises you to use the `new` keyboard in the inheriting interface to mark this as intentional:

```
public interface IModifiableFoo : IFoo
{
    new int Bar { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Don't use properties and interface inheritance here. Use regular methods and two separate interfaces:

```
public interface IFooReader
{
    int GetBar();
}

public interface IFooWriter
{
    void SetBar(int value);
}

public class FooImpl : IFooReader, IFooWriter
{
    public int GetBar() { /* ... */ }
    public void SetBar(int value) { /* ... */ }
}
```